# What is JSXIdentifier and how it differs from Identifier in AST?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jsx

As defined in JSX extensions

```
interface JSXIdentifier <: Identifier {
    type: "JSXIdentifier";
}
```

What is the purpose of JSXIdentifier vs. normal Identifier in AST?
https://github.com/facebook/jsx/blob/master/AST.md

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it looks like `JSXIdentifier` corresponds roughly to component or tag names in the JSX virtual DOM. For example in code

```
<ul></ul>
```

There would be `JSXOpeningElement` having a child `JSXIdentifier` with name set to "ul"

```
{
  name {
     name : "ul", 
     type: "JSXIdentifier",
     ...
  },
  type: "JSXOpeningElement",
  ...
}
```

The reason is to distinguish JavaScript identifiers from Virtual DOM element or React class names.

Thus, the normal `Identifier` is refererring to JavaScript execution context variables, while  the `JSXIdentifier` refers to Virtual DOM or React Class name.